# javascript check if string contains only alphanumeric characters + other special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string, validation

I have found this function to check if a string only contains alphanumeric characters:

```
function test ( value ) {
 if( value.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$")){
   alert('ok');
 }
}
test( 'Somevalue123' );
```

Now I would like to improve the above function to allow some other "special characters" like:

```
  (empty space)
' (single quote)
- (hyphen)
èàùìòÈÀÒÙÌéáúíóÉÁÚÍÓëäüïöËÄÜÏÖêâûîôÊÂÛÎÔç
```

And some symbols, like:

```
'_', '&', '.', ',', ':', '(', ')', '[', ']', '/', '+', '=', '?', '#', '@'
```

So I have try to update it and I was able to do so:

```
function test ( value, numbers, symbols ) {
 numbers = ( typeof numbers  === 'undefined' ) ? 0 : 1; // default numbers not allowed
 symbols = ( typeof symbols === 'undefined' ) ? 0 : 1; // default symbols not allowed
 value = value.replace(/è|à|ù|ì|ò|È|À|Ò|Ù|Ì|é|á|ú|í|ó|É|Á|Ú|Í|Ó|ë|ä|ü|ï|ö|Ë|Ä|Ü|Ï|Ö|ê|â|û|î|ô|Ê|Â|Û|Î|Ô|ç/g, '' ); // remove allowed characters before check

 // value = value.replace(/...???.../g, '' ); allow white space, single quote and symbols?

 if( numbers == 1 && value.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$")){ alert('ok'); } // number allowed
 else if( value.match("^[a-zA-Z ]*$")){ alert('ok'); } // number not allowed
}
```

**Not sure how to allow white space, single quote and symbols** (with Regex or value.replace() is the same for me).

Comment: Just add all these characters in the character class.

Comment: for empty space use \s , signle quote use \' ,  hypen \- and all other characters you can include in character class mean [ and ] as @Toto said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
/^[a-z0-9-\'_\.,:\(\)&\[\]\/+=\?#@ \xC0-\xFF]+$/i
```

#### Logic

- `/a-z0-9/i` will handle alphanumeric characters
- `\xC0-\xFF` will handle foreign character
- For symbols, you can list them individually.

An alternate could be listing all characters that are not allowed and use negate regex like

```
/^[^!~`\>\<]$/gi
```

Comment: thanks! how can I allow exclamation mark too in your first regex?

Comment: Thats what I said. You are allowing most of the characters. So you can have a negate regex instead. If not, just add it to symbol list.

Answer (score 4):

Use character class and add all the whitelisted characters in the character class.
Make sure the hyphen `-` is escaped by preceding it with backslash `\-` or added at the beginning or end in the character class.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9 èàùìòÈÀÒÙÌéáúíóÉÁÚÍÓëäüïöËÄÜÏÖêâûîôÊÂÛÎÔç'-]*$/
```

Also, use [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead of [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```
function test(value) {
    if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9 èàùìòÈÀÒÙÌéáúíóÉÁÚÍÓëäüïöËÄÜÏÖêâûîôÊÂÛÎÔç'-]*$/.test(value)) {
        alert('Ok');
    }
}
```